# What is usually way for updating entities in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

What approach is more preferable when updating entity in Hibernate? (new values comes from UI)

1) Retrive entity by ID (`Session#get()`), update it fileds with new values and call `Session#update()`.

2) Create new entity using `new` keyword, populate it with new values, insert ID (all values including ID received from UI) and call  `Session#update()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get entities from the database using session.get or queries, change it, commit the session.

Hibernate implements a very useful auto flush mechanism which detects changes in the session and synchronizes them automatically to the database.

Comment: ok, thank you. But what if I also need to update list of child entities (one-to-many)? Should I retrieve entire object graph? What if my object graph is really complicated (multiple child lists).

Comment: Good question. This is one of the key object object-relational gap covered by hibernate. It is possible to fetch a required object from object network and update back to database(if i'm not wrong).

Comment: When you change existing items in a list, the changes are recognized by Hibernate. Adding and removing items: If the children are mapped as composite elements, you don't have anything special to do. If the children are entities, you can insert new items using cascade=all and delete them explicitly or using cascade=all-delete-orphans. When you add or remove items, Hibernate doesn't need to load the whole list... Any more specific questions?